# grails no error and validate true but does not save. Hibernate no update

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

grails no error and validate true but does not save.

I have a method calling .save() but does not save the data in the db. I tried the ff:

1. called FailOnError: true but does not show anything that fails
2. validate(), it does return true
3. hasErrors(), it does return true put
4. put return objectInstance and showed that the value changed
5. set flush: false

but amidst all the things above not showing any validation failure, it still won't save in the db. I tried logging the hibernate and it does not show the "update" method for that instance. Mayeb that is why no update is happening. But my big question is why? Why would it not call the update when there is no error or anything? what am I missing. thanks.

here is my controller code:

```
def obpViewFlow = {

    start {
        action {
            def caseInstance = CmCase.get(params.caseId as Long)
            .....
        }
        on("success").to 'obpViewCase'
        on(Exception).to 'obpViewCase'
    }

    obpViewCase {
        on("edit").to 'edit'
        on("cancel").to 'cancel'
    }

    edit {
        redirect( action:"obpEdit", controller:"olderBlind", params:[caseId: flow.obpCaseInstance.olderBlind.cmCaseIdCmCase])
    }

    cancel {
        redirect( action:"obpView", controller:"olderBlind", params:[caseId: flow.obpCaseInstance.olderBlind.cmCaseIdCmCase])
    }def obpViewFlow = {

    start {
        action {
            def caseInstance = CmCase.get(params.caseId as Long)
            ObpCase obpCaseInstance = caseService.getObpCase(caseInstance)

            // set obpCaseInstance to flow scope, instance for view state
            flow.obpCaseInstance = obpCaseInstance
            if (params.created) {
                flash.message = "OBP Case has been successfully saved."
            }
        }
        on("success").to 'obpViewCase'
        on(Exception).to 'obpViewCase'
    }

    obpViewCase {
        on("edit").to 'edit'
        on("cancel").to 'cancel'
    }

    edit {
        redirect( action:"obpEdit", controller:"olderBlind", params:[caseId: flow.obpCaseInstance.olderBlind.cmCaseIdCmCase])
    }

    cancel {
        redirect( action:"obpView", controller:"olderBlind", params:[caseId: flow.obpCaseInstance.olderBlind.cmCaseIdCmCase])
    }
}

def obpEditFlow = {

    start {
        action {
            def caseInstance = CmCase.get(params.caseId as Long)
            flow.appDate = caseInstance.applicationDate
            ObpCase obpCaseInstance = caseService.getObpCase(caseInstance)

            // set obpCaseInstance to flow scope, instance for view state
            flow.obpCaseInstance = obpCaseInstance

            // get the following list to populate dropdown fields
            def residenceTypeList = ResidenceType.list()
            def visualImpairmentCauseList = VisualImpairmentCause.list()
            def referralSourceList = ReferralSource.list()

            [residencesType: residenceTypeList, visualImpairmentsCause: visualImpairmentCauseList, referralSources: referralSourceList]
        }
        on("success").to 'obpEditCase'
        on(Exception).to 'obpEditCase'
    }

    obpEditCase {
        on("save") {

            this.bindObpFields(flow, caseService, params)
            if (!this.bindAndValidateConstraints(flow, caseService, params)) {
                flow.olderBlindInstance = flow.obpCaseInstance.olderBlind
                return error()
            }
        }.to 'save'

        on("cancel").to 'cancel'
    }


    save {
        action {
            def obpCaseInstance = flow.obpCaseInstance
            try {
                HttpSession theSession = request.getSession();

                def obpCase = caseService.saveUpdateObpCase(obpCaseInstance, theSession.currentUser)

            }
            catch(Exception ie) {
                flow.exceptionMessage = ie.getMessage()
                throw ie
            }
        }

        on("success").to 'finish'
        on(Exception).to 'handleError'
    }

    finish {
    def obpViewFlow = {

    start {
        action {
            def caseInstance = CmCase.get(params.caseId as Long)
            ObpCase obpCaseInstance = caseService.getObpCase(caseInstance)

            // set obpCaseInstance to flow scope, instance for view state
            flow.obpCaseInstance = obpCaseInstance
            if (params.created) {
                flash.message = "OBP Case has been successfully saved."
            }
        }
        on("success").to 'obpViewCase'
        on(Exception).to 'obpViewCase'
    }

    obpViewCase {
        on("edit").to 'edit'
        on("cancel").to 'cancel'
    }

    edit {
        redirect( action:"obpEdit", controller:"olderBlind", params:[caseId: flow.obpCaseInstance.olderBlind.cmCaseIdCmCase])
    }

    cancel {
        redirect( action:"obpView", controller:"olderBlind", params:[caseId: flow.obpCaseInstance.olderBlind.cmCaseIdCmCase])
    }
}

def obpEditFlow = {

    start {
        action {
            def caseInstance = CmCase.get(params.caseId as Long)
            flow.appDate = caseInstance.applicationDate
            ObpCase obpCaseInstance = caseService.getObpCase(caseInstance)

            // set obpCaseInstance to flow scope, instance for view state
            flow.obpCaseInstance = obpCaseInstance

            // get the following list to populate dropdown fields
            def residenceTypeList = ResidenceType.list()
            def visualImpairmentCauseList = VisualImpairmentCause.list()
            def referralSourceList = ReferralSource.list()

            [residencesType: residenceTypeList, visualImpairmentsCause: visualImpairmentCauseList, referralSources: referralSourceList]
        }
        on("success").to 'obpEditCase'
        on(Exception).to 'obpEditCase'
    }

    obpEditCase {
        on("save") {

            this.bindObpFields(flow, caseService, params)
            if (!this.bindAndValidateConstraints(flow, caseService, params)) {
                flow.olderBlindInstance = flow.obpCaseInstance.olderBlind
                return error()
            }
        }.to 'save'

        on("cancel").to 'cancel'
    }


    save {
        action {
            def obpCaseInstance = flow.obpCaseInstance
            try {
                HttpSession theSession = request.getSession();

                def obpCase = caseService.saveUpdateObpCase(obpCaseInstance, theSession.currentUser)

            }
            catch(Exception ie) {
                flow.exceptionMessage = ie.getMessage()
                throw ie
            }
        }

        on("success").to 'finish'
        on(Exception).to 'handleError'
    }

    finish {

        redirect( action:"obpView", controller:"olderBlind", params:["created": "created", caseId: flow.obpCaseInstance.olderBlind.cmCaseIdCmCase])
    }

    handleError() {
        action {
            return success()
        }

        on("success").to 'obpEditCase'
    }

    cancel {
        redirect( action:"obpView", controller:"olderBlind", params:[caseId: flow.obpCaseInstance.olderBlind.cmCaseIdCmCase])
    }
}
        redirect( action:"obpView", controller:"olderBlind", params:["created": "created", caseId: flow.obpCaseInstance.olderBlind.cmCaseIdCmCase])
    }

    handleError() {
        action {
            return success()
        }

        on("success").to 'obpEditCase'
    }

    cancel {
        redirect( action:"obpView", controller:"olderBlind", params:[caseId: flow.obpCaseInstance.olderBlind.cmCaseIdCmCase])
    }
}
}

def obpEditFlow = {

    start {
        action {
            def caseInstance = CmCase.get(params.caseId as Long)
            ....
        }
        on("success").to 'obpEditCase'
        on(Exception).to 'obpEditCase'
    }

    obpEditCase {
        on("save") {

            this.bindObpFields(flow, caseService, params)
            if (!this.bindAndValidateConstraints(flow, caseService, params)) {
                flow.olderBlindInstance = flow.obpCaseInstance.olderBlind
                return error()
            }
        }.to 'save'

        on("cancel").to 'cancel'
    }


    save {
        action {
            def obpCaseInstance = flow.obpCaseInstance
            try {
                HttpSession theSession = request.getSession();

                def obpCase = caseService.saveUpdateObpCase(obpCaseInstance, theSession.currentUser)

            }
            catch(Exception ie) {
                flow.exceptionMessage = ie.getMessage()
                throw ie
            }
        }

        on("success").to 'finish'
        on(Exception).to 'handleError'
    }

    finish {

        redirect( action:"obpView", controller:"olderBlind", params:["created": "created", caseId: flow.obpCaseInstance.olderBlind.cmCaseIdCmCase])
    }

    handleError() {
        action {
            return success()
        }

        on("success").to 'obpEditCase'
    }

    cancel {
        redirect( action:"obpView", controller:"olderBlind", params:[caseId: flow.obpCaseInstance.olderBlind.cmCaseIdCmCase])
    }
}
```

here is my service code for the save

```
def CmCase saveUpdateCase(CmCase caseInstance, Users currentUser) {
    if (!caseInstance.save(flush:true)) {

        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            caseInstance.errors.allErrors.each { log.debug it }
        }

        throw new CaseException(message: "case.cmCase.exception", caseInstance: caseInstance)
    }
    return caseInstance
}
```

Hibernate showing all select and insert when doing other queries but not update.

Comment: update: I found out that when I call the objectInstance.get(id) again before save, it is now saving. But why do I have to re-get it?

Comment: Is that an action? If so, remove the `CmCase`. If it's a service method, remove `def`.

Comment: Do you pass the correct object to `saveUpdateCase`?

Comment: Where are you getting objInstance?

Comment: I was able to solve it by changing the .read() method to .get in the controller before and after save(when it retrns to view mode). the problem went away but generated another error wich is null transient when cancel button is clicked. SO I had to do a work around and assign the old value to the objectInstance by storing it in the flow. Getting it fresh from db would not work as when I get it, it gets the "dirty" data. I am still not satisfied with the workaround but it's the solution I can think of right now. I have modified the code for a clearer view.